# Posting JSON array with multiple objects into multiple rows in an SQL table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, express

I am trying to insert data from an API post request to fill out the rows in a MySQL table. I want the JSON array which has multiple objects in to occupy the rows in the table. I can't seem to figure it out using express JS. I am hoping someone can assist me with this problem.

Expected Result:

[image]

Below is my JS code snippet:

```
app.post('/dump', (req,res) => {
    let info = req.body;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `testStuff` (`j_object`) VALUES(?)";
    mysqlConnection.query(sql,[req.body],(err,rows,fields) => {
        if (!err)
            res.send('insert success');
        else
            console.log(err)
    }) 
});
```

Example Post Body:

```
{
    "test": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "location": "NY"
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "name": "Betty Doe",
            "location": "FL"
        }
    ]
}
```

MYSQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `testStuff` (
    `j_object` json NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: 1. you have to run a separate query for each object in your array 2. if you want to insert JSON into the table column, you have to use `[JSON.stringify(obj)]` where `obj` is the array element. You should also do basic debugging, like `console.log(req.body)`, especially before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO testStuff (j_object)
SELECT value
FROM JSON_TABLE(@post_body, '$.test[*]' COLUMNS (value JSON PATH '$')) jsontable
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8394f7e3e80942fcae063441bed7af1

In `var sql = ...` use `?` instead of `@post_body`.

Comment: I tried it and it returned **INSERT INTO testStuff (j_object) SELECT value FROM JSON_TABLE(`test` = '[object Object]', '[object Object]', '$.test[*]' COLUMNS (value JSON PATH '$')) jsontable** . Am I doing anything wrong? @Akina

Comment: @Putkimies *Am I doing anything wrong?* Please read [JSON Table Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) carefully. 1st parameter must be JSON document, not boolean expression. 2nd parameter must be base path which must be valid JSON path.